# Computed property that should fire and make an API call doesn't fire at all (Ember 2.8)

Tags: ember.js

I have two computed properties that should fire after `month` property changes. However only one of them fires and the other one doesn't.

`classesForMonth` fires once on init (when `month` is set for the first time) and doesn't fire after that.

I think it may be caused by `classesForMonth.content` syntax I have to use in template to render the Object received from the Promise after querying DS.

Please help me to get on a right track.

```
  classesForMonth: function() {
    console.log('hi im querying store') // doesn't fire on month change
    return this.get('store').query('class', {
      month: this.get('month') + 1,
    });
  }.property('month'),

  formattedMonth: function(){
    console.log('hi im formatting month') // does fire on month change
    return moment.months()[this.get('month')]
  }.property('month')
```

Comment: what version of ember are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ember 2.8.

Comment: do you use formattedMonth in your template?

Comment: Yes, I use both in my template. formattedMonth renders and changes correctly.

Comment: As a side note: you should use the `Ember.computed('month', function() {...})` notation instead. And yes, I think you are on the right track with the template. Can you confirm, that the return `this.get('store').query` finishes successfully? Have you injected the store? I assume you might have something like `classesForMonth.content` in you template? This might not call the binding logic you are looking for

Comment: It finishes succesfully. I realized that in fact I don't use the `classesForMonth` in template, this is a property from service which I modify in a controller and THEN render. Once I bind the property from controller to `myService.month` everything works great! Thank you for pushing me in the right direction @Remi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this computed property looks perfectly fine. I've build a little [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/4e77963b763b77ba85ba5407e5a7358b?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) to show that it's working.

Probably your problem is that you don't consume it right. A few things to notice:

- Computed properties are only executed when they are consumed. If you show show it in your template or `.get()` it otherwise, it won't compute.
- `store.query` returns a `DS.PromiseArray`.
- The `.content` property is nothing default for promises. It is a private API exclusive to `DS.PromiseArray` and `DS.PromiseObject`. And well, since its private you really *should not use it*.
- Returning a plain Promise in a computed property is not okay. Returning a `PromiseArray` or `PromiseObjet` is OK.
- If you have a `PromiseObject` or `PromiseArray` you can just use it like a normal object in your template. Ignore the Promise stuff.
- `store.query` should return multiple records. If you want only one use `store.queryRecord`.

So basically if you just do something like

```
{{#each classesForMonth as |class|}}
  ...
{{/each}}
```

this will work!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are querying from somewhere you and under some circumstances it is not wise to return a promise within a computed property, you might be better off with [observers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/object-model/observers/#toc_observers-and-asynchrony) like this:

```
classesForMonth: null
changeClasses: Ember.observer('month', function() {
    this.set('classesForMonth', this.get('store').query('class', {
      month: this.get('month') + 1,
    }));

    // or maybe better to avoid calling `.content` in you template
    this.get('store').query('class', {
      month: this.get('month') + 1,
    })).then(classes => this.set('classesForMonth', classes));
})
```

Comment: Mind to explain what's wrong with returning a promise and calling `.content` in template? I haven't had issues with that so far (other than this one caused by my own stupidity).

Comment: Its not "the ember way" ;). It is working, if you only want to display stuff. However, you might lose your binding e.g. when setting stuff from within the template. Plus, errors like yours are happening. If you want to actually use it as a computed property. Might want to have a look at @kumkanillams answer.

Comment: @Senthe because `.content` on `PromiseProxyMixin` is private. That should be reason enough. However it *is* save to return a `PromiseProxyMixin` and use `property.someProperty` in the template. Just don't use `content`.

Comment: @Remi Sorry but I think a observer is almost never the solution.